# Spark Scala: Pass a sub type to a function accepting the parent type

Tags: scala, oop, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an abstract class `A`. I also have classes `B` and `C` which inherit from class `A`.

```
abstract class A {
  def x: Int
}
case class B(i: Int) extends A {
  override def x = -i
}
case class C(i: Int) extends A {
  override def x = i
}
```

Given these classes, I construct the following RDD:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      Set(B(1), B(2)),
      Set(B(1), B(3)),
      Set(B(1), B(5))
    )).cache
      .zipWithIndex
      .map {case(k, v) => (v, k)}
```

I also have the following function that gets an RDD as the input and returns the count of each element:

```
def f(data: RDD[(Long, Set[A])]) = {
  data.flatMap({
    case (k, v) => v map { af =>
      (af, 1)
    }
  }).reduceByKey(_ + _)
}
```

Note that the RDD is accepting type `A`. Now, I expect `val x = f(data)` to return the counts as expected, as `B` is a sub-type of `A`, but I get the following compile error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, scala.collection.immutable.Set[B])]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Set[A])]
    val x = f(data)
```

This error goes away if I change the function signature to `f(data: RDD[(Long, Set[B])])`; however, I can't do that as I want to use other sub classes in the RDD (like `C`).

I have also tried the following approach:

```
def f[T <: A](data: RDD[(Long, Set[T])]) = {
  data.flatMap({
    case (k, v) => v map { af =>
      (af, 1)
    }
  }) reduceByKey(_ + _)
}
```

However, this also gives me the following run-time error:

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T, Int)]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value reduceByKey'?
      }) reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Just because B is a subtype of A Doesn't mean that Set[B] is a subtype of Set[A].  This is because `Set` is invariant.  You need to make sure your set is a Set[A]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set[T]` is invariant on `T`, meaning that given `A` subtype of `B`, `Set[A]` is not a subtype nor a supertype of `Set[B]`
`RDD[T]` is also invariant on `T` further restricting the options because, even if a covariant `Collection[+T]` is used (e.g. a `List[+T]`)  the same situation will arise.

We can resort to a polymorphic form of the method for an alternative:
What's missing in the version above is a `ClassTag` that Spark requires to preserve class information after erasure.

This should work:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag}
def f[T:ClassTag](data: RDD[(Long, Set[T])]) = {
  data.flatMap({
    case (k, v) => v map { af =>
      (af, 1)
    }
  }) reduceByKey(_ + _)
}
```

Let's see:

```
val intRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1l, Set(1,2,3)), (2L, Set(4,5,6))))
val res1= f(intRdd).collect
// Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((4,1), (1,1), (5,1), (6,1), (2,1), (3,1))

val strRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1l, Set("a","b","c")), (2L, Set("d","e","f"))))
val res2 = f(strRdd).collect
// Array[(String, Int)] = Array((d,1), (e,1), (a,1), (b,1), (f,1), (c,1))
```

Comment: This works perfectly where the RDD only contains instances of one object (e.g. int and string in your example). But suppose you have an RDD like this: `val mixRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1l, Set(1,2,3)), (2L, Set(4,5,6)), (3L, Set("a", "b"))))`. In this scenario, the code fails.

Comment: That's b/c Scala inferences a product type from that mix `Set[_ >: String with Int]` and cannot find a ClassTag for that. If you would coherce the type to a concrete type, then it would work: `val mixRdd: RDD[(Long, Set[Any])] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1l, Set(1,2,3)), (2L, Set(4,5,6)), (3L, Set("a", "b"))))`